# vaadin touchkit example application -- no ivy.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, vaadin, ivy

I have decided to try out Vaadin Touchkit for mobile application development, and am trying to get it installed and working on an example app. I have Windows 7 Pro, eclipse Luna, and maven. I'm happy to use something besides Maven, anything to make it work more easily.

The instructions say I can create a Vaadin project and then modify it to be a Vaadin Touchkit project. So I create a Vaadin project, using the Vaadin eclipse plug-in 3.0.0.

Step 1 in a list "After creating the project", says "Install the TouchKit library in the project by including it in the `ivy.xml`, as described in *Installing as Ivy Dependency*, and compile the widget set.

I think it odd that we're switching over to ivy from Maven, but ok. I go to the link indicated by the italics above, and find:

```
Include the following declaration inside the `dependencies` section in the `ivy.xml`.
```

But there is no ivy.xml file. I searched the whole directory tree. I know even less about ivy than I do Maven, so I dig around a little and find that ivy.xml is supposed to be in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory. But there is no such directory.

I suppose I could create an ivy.xml that contained nothing but the lines given in the instructions, but feel like trial-and-error in this kind of situation is not likely to be fruitful. Is there something else I was supposed to do to get ivy.xml in my eclipse Vaadin project? Is there some other way to get the TouchKit jar(s) on the classpath? Aren't I supposed to have a WEB-INF generated somewhere?

I presume others have gotten the TouchKit example to work in eclipse somehow -- if they can point me to a different way that does work, that'd be fine, I don't have to fix this one...

Answer (score 0):

Hm, lacking of Ivy.xml is very very old bug known by vaadin team. No one knows why sometimes it wont create it.(Maybe after some n-times attempts of recreating it may fix this).

Unluckily, you have to deal with maven

Comment: Ok, do you know how to do that? I've added the dependency to the pom.xml for the TouchKit, supposedly, and modified the servlet to extend the TouchkitServlet instead of the VaadinServlet. But it won't compile, because it cannot find the TouchkitServlet, and the instructions for putting that in place take me back to Ivy.

Comment: as far as i remember on compilation you need to have license key in order to compile widgetset.

Comment: well, am using the open source version, and haven't seen any instruction at all yet about a license key...

Comment: This might help you somehow: https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/touchkit/mobile-project.html 

And this one: https://github.com/vaadin/parking-demo

Comment: And since when Pro tools are free? They are trial( 30 days aas far as i remember) after expiration date, you will see prompt about licensing in console.

Comment: There is an open source version -- if you provide your source along with your application, no license fee is required.